# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime when inserting data to textbox

Tags: vb.net

Hello i have the following function to put all data to the exact textbox in my vb.net application :

```
If e.KeyChar = Chr(13) Then
    Call Koneksi()
    
    Dim CMD As OleDbCommand
    Dim RD As OleDbDataReader
    CMD = New OleDbCommand("select * From data_surat where kode_nomor='" & Textbox_kode_nomor.Text & "'", Conn)
    RD = CMD.ExecuteReader
    RD.Read()

    If Not RD.HasRows Then
        MsgBox("Kode Barang Tidak Ada")
        Textbox_kode_nomor.Focus()
    Else

        Textbox_surat_pengantar_rt.Text = RD.Item("no_srt_pngtr_rt")
        dtp_surat_pengantar_rt.Text = RD.Item("tgl_srt_pngtr_rt")
        Textbox_surat_pengantar_camat.Text = RD.Item("no_srt_pngtr_cmt")
        dtp_surat_Pengantar_camat.Text = RD.Item("tgl_srt_pngtr_cmt")
        Textbox_surat_penelitian_kuasa.Text = RD.Item("no_brt_pnlti_ksa")
        Textbox_surat_pengukuran_tanah.Text = RD.Item("no_srt_ukr")
        Textbox_surat_setuju_ukur.Text = RD.Item("no_srt_stj_ukr")
        Textbox_surat_kesepakatan.Text = RD.Item("no_srt_spkt")
        dtp_surat_acara_kesaksian.Text = RD.Item("tgl_brt_acr_sksi")
        dtp_surat_keterangan.Text = RD.Item("tgl_srt_ktrgn")
        dtp_surat_pemohon.Text = RD.Item("tgl_srt_pmh")
        dtp_tgl_surat_riwayat_kuasa.Text = RD.Item("tgl_srt_rwyt_ksa")
    End If
```

it suppose to insert all data from datatables into their precise textbox and datetimepicker...
but it keep getting error regarding date :

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect.

im struggling to know whats wrong with the code which probably due to the use of its formed as **dddd/MM/yyyy** because it work with other non-custom datetime....

any help will be truly appreciated...

Comment: `dddd/MM/yyyy` is not a valid format. Days are `0-31`, not `0-9999`.

Comment: Your program is vulnerable to SQL injection - and will break if someone types apostrophes into your `Textbox_kode_nomor` textbox so **you should fix that first** by using SQL parameters. Never create SQL strings by concatenating user input.

Comment: Also, you need to dispose of your database objects with a `Using` block.

Comment: What is the **exact type** (OLE DB type, not VB.NET type) of your date-picker columns, like `tgl_brt_acr_sksi`?

Answer (score 1):

The exception you're getting wouldn't be from a `TextBox`, it would be from a `DateTimePicker`. Don't set `DateTimePicker.Text`, instead set  `DateTimePicker.Value` with a `DateTime` value obtained from `OleDbDataReader.GetDateTime`.

Based on your control names I assume that the error is on this line:

```
dtp_surat_acara_kesaksian.Text = RD.Item("tgl_brt_acr_sksi")
```

Change your code to this:

- I've also converted your `OleDbCommand`'s SQL to use parameters instead of concatenation.
- And I've added `Using` blocks so you won't leak DB connections and other resources.
- I moved your repetitive population logic to a separate `Sub`.
- I added `Me.` qualifiers because that's my style.
- Note that the code below *does not* handle `NULL` results - but that's simple to handle: use VB.NET's `If( x, y, z )` operator (don't use `Iif` as it has eager evaluation which will cause errors).

  - Like so: `dtp.Value = If( rdr.IsDbNull( colNum ), DateTime.MinValue, rdr.GetDateTime( colNum ) )`

---

```
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(13) Then
        Call Me.Koneksi()

        Using cmd = Conn.CreateCommand())
            cmd.CommandText = "select * From data_surat where kode_nomor = ?;"

            OleDbParameter p = cmd.CreateParameter()
            p.Value = Textbox_kode_nomor.Text
            p.OleDbType = TODO
            cmd.Parameters.Add( p )

            Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

                If Not rdr.Read() Then
                    MsgBox("Kode Barang Tidak Ada")
                    Me.Textbox_kode_nomor.Focus()
                Else

                    Me.PopulateFromReader( rdr )

                End If

            End Using
        End Using
    End If

    Sub PopulateFromReader( OleDbDataReader rdr )

        ' Textboxes from Strings:
        Me.Textbox_surat_pengantar_rt    .Text = rdr.GetString("no_srt_pngtr_rt")
        Me.Textbox_surat_pengantar_camat .Text = rdr.GetString("no_srt_pngtr_cmt")
        Me.Textbox_surat_penelitian_kuasa.Text = rdr.GetString("no_brt_pnlti_ksa")
        Me.Textbox_surat_pengukuran_tanah.Text = rdr.GetString("no_srt_ukr")
        Me.Textbox_surat_setuju_ukur     .Text = rdr.GetString("no_srt_stj_ukr")
        Me.Textbox_surat_kesepakatan     .Text = rdr.GetString("no_srt_spkt")

        ' DateTimePickers from DateTimes:
        Me.dtp_surat_pengantar_rt        .Value = rdr.GetDateTime("tgl_srt_pngtr_rt")
        Me.dtp_surat_Pengantar_camat     .Value = rdr.GetDateTime("tgl_srt_pngtr_cmt")
        Me.dtp_surat_acara_kesaksian     .Value = rdr.GetDateTime("tgl_brt_acr_sksi")
        Me.dtp_surat_keterangan          .Value = rdr.GetDateTime("tgl_srt_ktrgn")
        Me.dtp_surat_pemohon             .Value = rdr.GetDateTime("tgl_srt_pmh")
        Me.dtp_tgl_surat_riwayat_kuasa   .Value = rdr.GetDateTime("tgl_srt_rwyt_ksa")



    End Sub
```

Comment: The only thing I would change, is to use a DataTable. I wouldn't hold the connection open while I updated the user interface.